# SQLite+ Embedded linux + Pygtk or QT/c++

Tags: qt, sqlite, pygtk, embedded-linux

I'm trying to build an application in my ARM9 (Freindly ARM) board that will get data via serial port and update the database.

Now I need to port SQLite in my embedded linux and write an application to store my values.

1. How to port SQLite to Embedded linux
2. Pygtk or Qt? Which is easy for a newbie ?

P.S: I know I'm asking a lot of questions in a single post, but I just thought giving the complete picture will help to give a better suggestion. If not personalized opinions, I'll be grateful if you guys can give me pointers to good links/tutorials. :) Thanks.

Comment: The sqlite source is plain C, it probably doesn't need any porting for your platform. But if Qt or python+Gtk aren't available for your target, those will quite possibly require a _huge_ porting effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**

You don't need to port sqlite to the your Freindly ARM ARMv9 board.(as Mat has already mentioned)

I am going to assume that you have a [mini2440](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/mini2440) or
a [micro2440](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/micro2440).

Either way it is a Samsung S3C2440 chip.

sqlite works on this board as per the following [thread](http://www.friendlyarm.net/forum/topic/1522).

Sumeet's post has cross compliation instructions.

Qt cross compliation works as per the following [thread](http://www.friendlyarm.net/forum/topic/439)

So does Python and Gtk.

You have 2 options when it comes to cross-compliation,

1. Cross compile yourself
2. Use a tool like buildroot or openembedded's bitbake

For further resources on cross-compliation and building packages for this board
see the following resources.

- [mini2440 Google Code Project](http://code.google.com/p/mini2440/), specifically see the wiki and download sections
- [FriendlyArm Forum](http://www.friendlyarm.net/forum/)
- [FriendlyArm Downloads](http://www.friendlyarm.net/downloads)
- [linuxmce mini2440 wiki page](http://wiki.linuxmce.org/index.php/Mini2440)
- [HOWTO-Getting-Started-With-OpenEmbedded for mini2440](http://bill.station51.net/index.php?post/2010/01/26/HOWTO%3A-Getting-Started-With-OpenEmbedded)
- [Further HOWTOs](http://bill.station51.net/index.php)

**2.**

PyGTK and PyQt are both relatively easy to learn in comparison to learning and debugging cross compilation on embedded architectures. If by Qt you didn't mean PyQt but instead meant C++ and Qt, then it not only becomes a choice of GUI toolkit, but also of language. I don't know your familiarity with Python or with C++, so I don't know which would be easier for you.

Which one you want to use is up to you.

Resources for both are linked to below

- [PyQt4 Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/)
- [PyGTK Tutorial](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/)